# Class App\Policies\StatusPolicy does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I setup my classes so I can use [Laravel Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization) and use the Policies feature. But I keep getting this error (Class App\Policies\StatusPolicy does not exist) when defining the middleware to my methods. This is what I have:

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Status' => 'App\Policies\StatusPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

StatusController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Status;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StatusController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('can:list,App\Status')->only('index');
         $this->middleware('can:update,status')->only('edit');
    }

    // ...
```

StatusPolicy.php (generated by php artisan make:policy StatusPolicy --model=Status

```
namespace Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Status;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class StatusPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Verifica se o usuário tem permissão para listar os status.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function list(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the status.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Status  $status
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Status $status)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create statuses.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the status.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Status  $status
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Status $status)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the status.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Status  $status
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Status $status)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Your namespace in the class seems to be `Policies` not `App\Policies`.  Laravel's generators shouldn't have created it like this unless you modified something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.

For some reason, the command `php artisan make:policy` created a file with a wrong namespace. The fix was to change the namespace in the StatusPolicy.php file:

From `namespace Policies;`
To `namespace App\Policies;`

Comment: I too used the `php artisan make:policy` generator and it put my `Policies` folder under `App`, but I put my models in `App\Models`. I moved the `Policies` folder there, but forgot to update the namespace code to `namespace App\Models\Policies`. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

change the namespace in your StatusPolicy class to App\Policies;